# Why does pathlib.Path(".").parent not return ".."?

Tags: python, path, pathlib

I cannot seem to get the parent of `"."` correctly using `pathlib`:

```py
>>> Path(".").parent
PosixPath(".")
```

Even worse, `Path(".")` is its own parent:

```py
>>> Path(".").parent == Path(".")
True
```

I would expect `Path(".").parent == Path("..")` instead - what am I missing?

**Edit:** I am aware that this is documented, but I am interested in *why* this is the case, especially considering that `Path("some.file") == Path(".")` (as expected).

Comment: You're supposed to start by [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) before coming here - it addresses this.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica the docs say "You cannot go past an anchor, or empty path" - they don't say *why*.

Comment: The *why* is "This is a purely lexical operation". It's not resolving any paths, it's just working with the string it has and returning the best answer it can find given that string.

Comment: @Kemp returning `..` for `.` is very much possible by "just working with the string it has". If `..` is not the best answer in every case - then *why*?

Answer (score 3):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent):

> This is a purely lexical operation

and

> You cannot go past an anchor, or empty path

and it specifically calls out this behaviour in an example:

```
>>> p = PurePosixPath('.')
>>> p.parent
PurePosixPath('.')
```

It's not resolving the path and finding the actual parent, it's working with the string it has and returning the best answer it can find given that string.

You would have to call [`resolve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) first before fetching the parent. For example

```
Path('.').resolve().parent
```

will give the correct answer.

Comment: Can I not, with a purely lexical operation, return `".."` for "`.`"? (Maybe I misunderstand what *lexical* means.)

Comment: In this instance I take it to mean that it's simply inspecting the string it has been given and not attempting to relate it to actual paths. So it'd split the string up, attempt to remove the final segment, and then return the rest joined back together.

Comment: Sorry, that explanation is not convincing to me. If it is true, then why does `Path("file.txt").parent` return `Path(".")`? The original path does not contain any `.`.

Comment: Simple answer: I don't know, I didn't write the code or the documentation. As a guess, if it runs out of things in the path and it looked like a relative path then it just returns `'.'`. Either way, this is documented behaviour and the "why" is because it's not resolving any paths, it's just working with the string it has and returning the best answer it can find given that string.

Comment: Would it make sense to return `..` as the parent of `.`? Possibly. But they had to make a call about how many special cases they were willing to add and the answer likely ended up "none". Each special case adds more testing load, more documentation load, and lulls more people into thinking their own special case will be accommodated when it might not be.

Comment: (Also, I can think of at least one situation in which it doesn't make sense to return `..` for the parent of `.` and given that it's not resolving the path it can't know if it's in that situation or not.)

Comment: Care to share that "at least one situation"? ;)

Comment: If your current directory is the root of the drive then `..` would be nonsensical. Doing it properly by resolving the path first gives you the drive root back again when you try to access parent.

Comment: Well, `cd / && cd ..` or even `cd /..` is syntactically valid and does not throw an error, even it it's "nonsensical". Speaking of which, do you see how you are contradicting yourself? You say that `.parent` is a purely lexical operation, but at the same time, you say that `Path(".").parent` is "nonsensical" when in `/`. These two arguments do not go together well.

Comment: In summary, I do not see any reason why `.parent` shouldn't be a (purely lexical) operation which behaves similarly to `cd ..`, so returning `..` for `.` still makes total sense to me.

Comment: You'll have to ask the people that made the original decisions, there's no point arguing with me about what you think it should do. I only have access to the same information you do. As it stands, this is the documented behaviour - you can't go past an anchor or an empty path.